# How to connect to a computer under a subnet mask of a router on my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, subnet

Edit: Let me know how to not use a link for the image as well if you want, and instead just post it on question itself.

So I have a router (let's call it R) that's on my network (call it NB) and under that router there's a subnet mask (NC) on which there's a computer D. I want to connect (windows remote desktop and other things) from my computer (computer A) which is on NB.

So, A and R are on network NB, there's NC under R and D is on NC. Here's an image to illustrate

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBBJD.png]

I know IP addresses of A and R on NB and of D on NC and I have access to R's administration page (NC's administration). I can use remote desktop connection from D to A by putting in A's IP address on NB, but not the reverse, which is what I need to do.

How can I connect from A to D? Is there any other information you need?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please explain how the router R is configured? Is NAT turned on? Does it have static routes?

Comment: What are the IP addresses in NB and R? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc , on NB, My computer A is on ABC . XYZ . 6 . 223 and R is on ABC . XYZ . 7 . 83/27. In NC, Computer D is on 192.168.1.140 . A and D both have static IPs on their respective networks.

Comment: @user253751 I don't know how to find out if NAT is turned on. D has a static ip address on NC (as does A on NB) if that's what you mean by R having static routes

Comment: Change the netmask on both routers and computers to `255.255.0.0`. All devices will then be on the `ABC.XYZ*` network segmemt.

Comment: It seems your networking level of knowledge is quite basic. Is there any reason why the router R *needs* to act as a router and have a different subnet? This might be more complicated than necessary. If you set R to "bridge mode" and turn off "DHCP server" on R, it will just extend the existing network without creating a new one.